# Is this a transformer, a choke or something else?

Tags: identification

I thought that the component which is shown in the following picture is a transformer. But when I opened it I saw that the end of the coil on top (with thicker wire) was soldered to the beginning of the coil beneath it (with thinner wire). The three pins on one side were from to the coil on top, and the other two pins came out from the second coil near the end of it (both pins).

Its size is approximately 3 cm x 3 cm x 3 cm. It's from a circuit which turns on a 60 cm long 20 Watts tubular fluorescent lamp by a 6 V battery. Both of those two pins on one side are directly connected to one side of the lamp (apparently for preheating).

So what is this component and what does it basically do?

[image]

Comment: Sure looks like a transformer to me. Probably one with a center tap. Could you draw a schematic symbol for the device showing the internal connections you observed?

Comment: Do you have a better picture? Is there any markings on it? How big is it? Have you do a continuity test on all the pins and your sure that they're all connected? Where did you get the component?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/egq3H.png

Comment: @Jack. Its size is approximately 3 cm x 3 cm x 3 cm. It's from a circuit which turns on a 60 cm long 20 Watts tubular fluorescent lamp by a 6 V battery. Both of those two pins on one side are directly connected to one side of the lamp (apparently for preheating).

Comment: @Jack. Yes, I did a continuity check before opening it. The resistance from one side to the other was only a few ohms. And I thought that it was a dead transformer. That's why I opened it. No markings were on it. Seemed to be handmade.

Comment: @apadana like Tony shows it looks like a center tapped transformer. But if your saying that the wires from both sides were intentionally soldered together, then I'm not so sure. Easier ways to drive a 20W from 6V than what looks like an EI30